# Where can I get a copy of JDK 1.0.2 JavaDocs?

Tags: history, javadoc, java

I'm doing a bit of research for a blog post involving the evolution of a specific part of the Java API.  To that end, I've been able to find JavaDocs going all the way back to JDK 1.1, but not to the original 1.0.

Sun has removed any trace of JDK 1.0 JavaDocs from [sun.com](http://java.sun.com).  I've Googled high and low, near and far, but cannot find anything.  Nothing shows up on [archive.org](http://www.archive.org) either.

Any ideas?

**Where can I get a copy of JDK 1.0.2 JavaDocs?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I Found it at: http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/

Answer (score 2):

The very first google answer links to http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/java_api/packages.html which looke like doc for java 1.0

Comment: I musta had too many parameters in my search.  Over complicating things again....

Answer (score 2):

Web archive looks promising:
http://web.archive.org/web/19990504101333/www.java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.0.2/apidocs.html

Comment: Humph...I used their search but got nothing.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very intuitive.  You have to know the domain you're interested in to get the best results and then it's just a matter of narrowing in on what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

JDK-1_0_2-apidocs-long.zip is an archive of these documents. One might download this file from the internet, unzip it, and open index.html. I found a link to this file from http://www.pascal-man.com/download/download-jdk.shtml

The SHA256 of this file is

- fede377a3476a929966ff7dde6819948cb3be44ddb0cb1e0f388ed886e303408

Comment: Sadly, not a valid link anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it here: http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/java/javasoft-docs/jdk1.0.2/. Searched by file name "JDK-1_0_2-apidocs-long.zip"

Comment: Sadly, not a valid link anymore.